# CURL ERROR DOWNLOAD : Recv failure : Connection was reset (using c++)

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have a console application using C++
This application only serves to download files from the central server to the client
I use curl to api the download.
but there is a problem from the client environment side
in the dev environment it is successful
currently only using http to download it.
Here's a screenshot of the console app.
there is an error Recv failure: Connection was reset
Please help
thanks

[screenshot error application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeybr.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what you need help with. We can't do much of an analysis from seeing that picture. Please show a [mre] and read this excerpt from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.